# 「どうあろうと」と「どうあっても」 の違いは何ですか

Tags: grammar

In this example sentence from the manga Death Note,

"推理の過程が**どうあろうと**この女の握っている事は真実"

When I looked for the meaning on weblio it suggested どうあっても as meaning the same thing? My Rikaikun doesn't come with an answer for どうあろうと but it knows どうあっても, are they roughly the same meaning?

Thank you for your help!　ありがとうございます！

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28615/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どうあろうと No matter how (推理の過程) would be

どうあっても No matter how (推理の過程) is

I think the semantic difference is small in the context.

> この女の握っている事は真実

This part baffles me as to the meaning of the whole sentence. この女 did the detective work?

Comment: Thank you for your help!
The English translation I found on the same page says something like "No matter how she did her reasoning, what she found is the truth"
But that semantic difference really clears it up!
Although...I'm still not sure why he didn't just say どうあっても hahaha

ありがとうございました！